# Read firebase database and store in string variable fail

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read user data from Firebase but the username variable is always nil.

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
let storageRef = storage.reference()
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
let canvasName = NSUUID().uuidString
var username: String? = nil

//get username
self.ref.child("Users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let usersProfile = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    let userProfile = usersProfile![userID!] as? NSDictionary
    username = userProfile!["Username"] as? String            
}) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

//create new canvas
let canvasValue:[String:Any] = ["UserID":userID!,
                                "Username": username!,//always nil 
                                "TimeCreated": NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970,
                               ]
let canvasAutoID = self.ref.child("Users").child(userID!).child("Canvas").childByAutoId().key
    self.ref.child("Canvas").child(canvasAutoID!).setValue(canvasValue)
```

Here's an image of the firebase database.

[image: image here]

Comment: Looks like you're accessing `username` outside of the block; this is an asynchronous operation. Of course it's nil, it hasn't been set yet by the time it hits that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`observeSingleEvent` works asynchronously. It might have to make a network request to get that data, so the closure will run at some indeterminate time after the function is called. The code after it, where you try to access `username`, runs first, meaning `username` still has its initial value `nil`. You can fix this by moving your code inside the closure, as shown below, or by putting it in another function that you call from inside the closure.

```swift
//get username
self.ref.child("Users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let usersProfile = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    let userProfile = usersProfile![userID!] as? NSDictionary
    username = userProfile!["Username"] as? String 
    //create new canvas
    let canvasValue:[String:Any] = ["UserID":userID!,
                                    "Username": username!, 
                                    "TimeCreated": NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970,
                                   ]
    let canvasAutoID = self.ref.child("Users").child(userID!).child("Canvas").childByAutoId().key
    self.ref.child("Canvas").child(canvasAutoID!).setValue(canvasValue)          
}) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get your username like below.

```
 self.ref.child("Users").observe(.value) { (snapshot) 
          if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
               for users in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {  
                     let userObject = users.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                     let userName  = userObject?["Username"] as! String 
                     print(userName)
                }
            } else {
                print("No users")
            }
      }
```